# With react-redux-firebase reconnect to firebase after a logout

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I have a `react-redux-firebase` App showing public and private data.

I connect the Firebase database during the first render process as shown in the [complete simple example](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/master/examples/complete/simple/src/Home.js).

In a nested component a button triggers the `props.firebase.logout()` method and all my data connected to Firebase goes away, even the public ones.

Is there a proper way to reconnect to the database and the redux store in order to view the public data again?

Currently I do a horrible `window.location.reload()` and I would like to avoid this.

Thanx a lot,
Gionatan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping certain data within the firebase section of the redux store on logout is not currently supported, but is a great idea. [I opened an issue to track](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/125) adding a feature that should support your use case.

For now, if you are calling `firebase.logout()` you can redirect to another page that has listeners for your public data. Something like this:

```
this.props.firebase.logout()
  .then(() => {
     // redirect to a route that has listeners with your public data
     this.context.router.push('/someroute');
   })
```

Disclosure:

I am the author of react-redux-firebase